# Elastic search replica selection mechanism

Tags: elasticsearch

Anyone has information regarding the replica selection mechanism that Elasticsearch uses? I mean the basis on which a particular replica of a shard is selected to serve a query. I have tried to look at Elastic search documentation but I was unable to find the information.
Kindly share any relevant resource.

Comment: What do you mean by replica selection?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: You configure the number of replicas your want for your primary data nodes in ElasticSearch. ES then looks after the replication with some configurable settings.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the answer via discussion on ElasticSearch forums. To put it simply, ElasticSearch uses a round robin scheme to select replicas to respond to queries from within a replica group (sort-of). This replica group, according to my understanding, is selected based on the the [awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#allocation-awareness) and [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-preference.html) attributes that has been provided in configuration.